# Two Select Drop down boxes, the first updates the second NO AJAX

Tags: javascript, forms, select, drop-down-menu

I need two drop down form  boxes. Selecting content in the first one updates the second one.

However I do not want to use AJAX JSON updating in the Javascript (I've found these online but can't get them working on my server). What I would rather do is generate a list when the page loads and have the Javascript pull from a list already loaded on the page. The data is coming from a mySQL database but since it is preloaded on the page its faster.

I can handle getting the data from the database but what I need is the JS that changes the  for the second drop down box getting the data from a variable list or some other function rather then a AJAX JSON update.

I'll use jquery if I can but all I find online is AJAX versions of this script.

Comment: How would you decide which pre-loaded list to load in to the 2nd element when someone change an option in the first list ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="firstselect" onchange="changeMe(id)" />

<script>
function changeMe(id) {
  var options1=[1,2,3,4];
  var options2=[2,3,4,5];

  var options = null;
  if (id = 1) {
    var options = options1;
  } else {
    var options = options2;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = options[i];
    optn.value = options[i];
    $('secondSelect').add(option, i);
  }
}
</script>
```